# Configure options with ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I have options class as below:

```
public class SomeOptions : RemoteAuthenticationOptions
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and class that inherit IPostConfigurationOptions for this options configuration:

```
public class SomeOptionsPostConfigureOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<SomeOptions>
    {
        private readonly IDataProtectionProvider _dataProtectionProvider;
    
        public SomeOptionsPostConfigureOptions(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
        {
            _dataProtectionProvider = dataProtectionProvider;
        }
    
        public void PostConfigure(string name, SomeOptions options)
        {
            options.DataProtectionProvider ??= _dataProtectionProvider;
            // and other code...
        }
    }
```

then I use this configuration in Program.cs as here:

```
services.ConfigureOptions<SomeOptions>();
```

When I run this app, I get an exception:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: 'No IConfigureOptions<>, IPostConfigureOptions<>, 
or IValidateOptions<> implementations were found.'
```

Why? There is an configuration implementation for proper options, so I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you mean `ConfigureOptions<SomeOptionsPostConfigureOptions>()`

Comment: Wrote it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean ConfigureOptions<SomeOptionsPostConfigureOptions>()? That will look at the specified type for known interfaces and register them with the container.